# getting a title trough beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

[image of div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbxdr.png)

Im trying to get the title, keep in mind it changes

my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.rolimons.com/deals'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('div', title='here the title changes depending on the item'))
```

Comment: if you want  to get `div` with `title` then use `title=True`

Comment: you have the most common problem: page uses `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.